# Powershell Filtering with Where-Object not applying

Tags: powershell, filtering

I'm having an issue with following piece of code:

```
$NodeList = (get-scvmhostcluster ClusterName| where-object {$_.nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname -ne "Host001.Domain.Tld"}).nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname
```

Normally this should filter from the list of Hosts the "Host001.Domain.tld" out of the list. (Host001 up to Host014 is what this list normally generates, unfiltered).

However, when running the script block and seeing whats in the $NodeList variable I get every single object as if the filter was not applied.

I've been trying to debug this for a few hours now but to no avail.

Anyone able to point out my wrongdoings ?

Regards,

Comment: If you execute`get-scvmhostcluster ClusterName| foreach-object {$_.nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname}` do you get any values?

Comment: Yes, I get all the FQDN's of the Host's in the Cluster.

Comment: is `fullyqualifieddomainname` a string? if you put a breakpoint at the where-object block, and check `$_.nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname.GetType()` what do you get?

Comment: I also wonder if there is whitespace on the string that is causing the comparison to fail. Perhaps you will get results from `where-object {$_.nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname -notlike "*Host001.Domain.Tld*"}`

Comment: Matt, no whitespaces (your codeblock didn't change anything)

Micky, String objects yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-SCVMHostCluster ClusterName` returns a single cluster object.

When you pipe it to `Where-Object`, you have the following:

1. `$_.Nodes` is a collection of objects with a `fullyqualifieddomainname` property of type `string`
2. `$_.Nodes.fullyqualifieddomainname` is therefore a collection of collections of strings

`Where-Object` will only collapse the first "level" of collections, it won't go deeper - and therefore your filter will never match anything, a collection of string arrays will never match the lone string you're comparing against.

Here is what I would do, collapsing the first level by selecting the `Nodes` property (broken into statements for readability, feel free to pipe it in one statement):

```
$Nodes = Get-SCVMHostCluster ClusterName|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Nodes
$NodeList = $Nodes |Where-Object {$_.fullyqualifieddomainname -ne "Host001.domain.tld"}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullyqualifieddomainname
```